# Can a workflow move documents into a document set in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-set

Can a workflow move documents into a document set (within the same library) in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, i'm struggling over the exact same issue, well i need to move a current item to another library but into a Doc Set. From what i've found so far it can be done but you need to use the 'Update Item' action and update the 'Path and Name' to be "document set name/current item name".

I'll get back to you if I get anything else working.

Luke